# If ㅆ meets the consonant ㅅ, will the resulting sound be a double " ss "?

Tags: pronunciation

i was just wondering if its okay to transliterate or pronounce it to kuossumnida 그었습니다 or should it sound like kuot sumnida with the t stops ? or is it okay if this two ㅆ+ㅅ = ㅆ or double ss ? hence it will sound kuwos sumnida not kuot sumnida and could you please tell me the name of the rule of this sound change . thank you ;)

Comment: Briefly put, there will be no hard stop after the ㅆ when followed by ㅅ.

Comment: thank you so much :) no name for that rule ? could you give me another word :) that has this kind of sound change . please and thank you .

Comment: The easiest and most prevalent example is 있습니다 (to have, to be). I do not know of any official name for this rule however. It is sort of like the rule that "ch" has a sound change in English. It is just "the rule."

Comment: thank you ever so much for taking the time :) to comment here yeah........... i was attempting to edit my comment since i would like to inform :) you that i want a word that has ㅆ double shiot 쌍시옷followed by a 시옷 and not a stem + formal high suffix sumnida . i see :) now i am even more curious about this rule ;) i mean the name of the rule in korean language

Comment: ㅆ followed by ㅅ in the same word is always a continuous 's' sound

Answer (score 4):

습니다 was actually historically spelled 읍니다 when it was followed by a ㅆ final until 1988.[image: A car ad from the 1980's.]

It was changed to 습니다 in the reform of 1988. The reason was that there was no reason to differentiate between 읍니다 and 습니다, because no one did in real life.

As for ㅆㅅ or ㅅㅅ being pronounced as the same sound as ㅆ, is nowhere to be found on the Standard Pronunciation Rules. Actually, 했습니다 *should* be pronounced as [핻씀니다], according to those rules. That's because the rule states that *the finals preceding a consonant must be pronounced as one of these seven consonants: ㄱ,ㄴ,ㄷ,ㄹ,ㅁ,ㅂ,ㅇ*.([표준 발음법 제4장 제8항](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000100&mn_id=95))

So very strictly speaking, 그었습니다 pronounced like [그어씀니다] is not the standard.

Comment: love the *Bongo* ad!

Comment: thank you so much yes yes i know that :) rule :( hmm.. actually i saw that rule from an app called rieul the rules says 시옷  following받침with ㄱㄷㅂ sound is pronounce as 쌍시옷 ㄷ,ㅌ,ㅈ,ㅊㅅ,ㅆ+ㅅ = ㄷ + ㅆ like 헛소리 must be pronounce as 헏쏘리 instead of 허쏘리 where the ㄷ stops is not heard at all like it was assimilated or something :( thank you so much

Comment: but does that mean someone is pronouncing it like that :( even if its not standard  i mean would it be  okay for me to pronounce it like that since it flows better than with a ㄷ stop :) or ???? maybe i should still pronounce the ㄷ + ㅆ which is the standard one . thank you for helping me ;) maybe that question was stupid so :( i will apologize now . i am terribly sorry for my innocence . and thank you for sharing your knowledge ;)

Comment: that page was really nice i wanted one of those . do you happen to have all the pronunciation rules 음소변동 on that website . please send me the link :) thank you mujjin :)

Comment: @majutsushimika That page I linked to is the official page of the Institute of Korean Language. So it *is* the standard source to look up sound change rules. Anything that is not listed on that page is not the standard.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb and claim that MujjinGun's answer is a bit misleading, while technically correct.

That is, if the standard requires 그었습니다 to sound as [그얻씀니다] (with a ㄷ sound in the middle), then I think it is either the error of the standard, or maybe the actual pronunciation of Korean has changed to such a degree that the standard is no longer an accurate representation of the real language.

It seems that having a ㄷ+ㅅ(ㅆ) cluster should create a sound similar to "tsu (つ)" in Japanese.  But I don't think I've ever heard that sound in Korean.  (Well of course I could be wrong, because if *I* don't use that sound then my brain will filter the sound out even if others use it, but I think someone would have noticed and remarked on it.)  Also, Koreans learning Japanese frequently have a difficulty pronouncing the "tsu" sound, which shouldn't be the case if the sound was actually used in Korean.

So I think it is always pronounced as [그어씀니다] in real life.

Comment: yeah つ in japanese is like double of kk or tt けっこう/たった the tsu here called 促音anyway :) there is another word in korean conjugated to 지마 and the verb is 늦다 but if we conjugate 늦지마 another case of two 받침 so when this ㅈ+ㅈ = ㅉ yes ? so there is no ㄷ stop here or would this be same like ㅆ + ㅅ = ㅆ  and as usual the ㄷ somewhat disappear and it was like um..... assimilated or what ? like when this two ㅆ+ㅅ  meet and sounds like ㅆ without the ㄷ stop of course

Comment: if this was any part of the rule i would like to know its name in korean :) or whatever they named that rule ;) i am so curious i mean if it did exist . if not then i will pronounce it as 경음화

Comment: The standard requires “ㅅ＋ㅆ＝ㄷㅆ” but practically nobody speaks like that; **it’s assimilated into one “ㅆ.”** It’s a bit shocking to me how the standard differs from the current use.