# Pronunciation of ㅆ

Tags: pronunciation

I started studying Korean a few days ago though this site https://www.howtostudykorean.com and in the first few lessons it taught me to pronounce ㅆ as 'ss'. But then I reached lesson 5 and listened to this recording https://www.howtostudykorean.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Lesson-5-6-I-ate-rice.mp3 of this example:

> 나는 밥을 먹었다

And she clearly says "mokotta" and not "mokossta". So where is that ㅆ? I studied Japanese beforehand so I'm assuming ㅆ is actually more like っつ? Maybe at the end of a syllable it becomes something like っ?

Comment: 1. Responding to your last sentence: yes. 2. If you want to learn pronunciation, don't learn from howtostudykorean. You may learn from it for grammars. 3. Can you search for more info. on the web before asking this question?

Comment: +1 to what @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy said, and I'd recommend getting a good textbook if you're starting out rather than using websites.

Comment: if I remember correctly this is a dupe

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/75/when-are-%E3%85%85-and-%E3%85%86-pronounced-as-stops

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/if-%E3%85%86-meets-the-consonant-%E3%85%85-will-the-resulting-sound-be-a-double-ss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ㅆ here is a 받침 , which means the "end" consonant in a syllable block.  For example, in 먹 the 받침 is ㄱ.  If the next syllable does not start with a vowel, such as 다, (or it is the last syllable) this syllable (if it has a 받침) is not pronounced normally.  Instead, it is pronounced like an unreleased stop ([t], [k],[p], [n] etc.) based on the place of the sound.  Since ㅆ is a dental/alveolar sound (the tongue is near the teeth), it becomes a dental stop here [t].  Since the next sound is 다, this means there are two "t" sounds, causing it to be a tense sound "tt"

Comment: Can you add an explanation of 있는? Is the first syllable pronounced as 인 or as 이 or something else?

Comment: @Wilson 있는 is pronounced as 인는 because of the nasal assimilation. The process can be shown as 있는 → [읻]는 → [인는]. The correct romanization of 있는 for general purposes is *inneun* (or *in-neun*) not itneun.